# LyX + Grammarly (or other external grammar checkers)

Tags: lyx, spelling, grammar

LyX has some capabilities for sending/receiving words in a server. I am wondering if it is possible to integrate Grammarly (or similar software) to LyX.

Does anyone know how to configure LyX for this?

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing is that LyX has support for ChkTeX and this can be leveraged to integrate grammar checking with [Language Tool](https://languagetool.org/). There is, however, no continuous grammar checking (e.g., blue wavy lines under grammar mistakes). Please see [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX-GrammarChecker) for instructions on how to set up ChkTeX in LyX to use Language Tool.

Grammarly does not have an API. You can export to plain text, or copy/paste, to use Grammarly, but that would not give you good integration with LyX.